# ¿ Que significa error ENOSPC al correr un servidor?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, http-post, localhost

Hola al correr una aplicación en localhost me lanza el siguiente error. Antes no pasaba, he modificado algo el archivo server.js donde corre el puerto, pero nunca antes me había salido esto. El puerto corre como se ve, pasa build, gulp y la pagina se puede abrir, pero esto me tiene preocupado, pues no se como encontrar que significa y a que se debe.

Les muestro el código del servidor, que al modificar es cuando comenzó el error, porque la única referencia que veo es al package.json

```
Michaelgram escuchando en el puerto 3000
[18:22:53] Using gulpfile ~/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/Gulpfile.js
[18:22:53] Starting 'watch'...
[18:22:53] Finished 'watch' after 52 ms
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/package.json'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:161:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1227:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:159:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:257:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:39:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:159:5)`
```

```js
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var ext = require('file-extension')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var expressSession = require('express-session')
var passport = require('passport')
var michaelgram = require('michaelgram-client')
var aws = require('aws-sdk')
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3')

var config = require('./config')
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

let client = michaelgram.createClient(config.client)

s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey
})

let storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: 'michaelgram',
  acl: 'public-read',
  metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname })
  },
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, +Date.now() + '.' + ext(file.originalname))

  }
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('picture')

let app = express()


app.set(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: config.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram' })
})

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signup' })
})

app.post('/signup', function (req,res) {
  let user = req.body
  client.saveUser(user, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)

    res.redirect('/signin')
  })
})

app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signin' })
})

app.get('/api/pictures', function (req, res, next) {
  let pictures = [
    {
      user: {
        username: 'miguelito',
        avatar: ''
      },
      url: 'office.jpg',
      likes: 0,
      liked: false,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime()
    },
    {
      user: {
        username: 'miguelito',
        avatar: ''
      },
      url: 'office.jpg',
      likes: 1,
      liked: true,
      createdAt: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 10)
    }
  ];

  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send(pictures)
  }, 2000)
});

app.post('/api/pictures', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send("Error uploading file")
    }
    res.send('File uploaded')
  })
})

app.get('/api/user/:username', (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    username: 'miguelito',
    avatar: '',
    pictures: [

    ]
  }

  res.send(user);
})

app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` })
})

app.get('/:username/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` })
})

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log('Hubo un error'), process.exit(1)

  console.log('Michaelgram escuchando en el puerto 3000')
})
```

Las líneas que añadi fueron las de requerir el otro módulo: `var michaelgram = require('michaelgram-client')` que enlace, las que muestro bajo estas líneas.
Muchas gracias

```js
    let client = michaelgram.createClient(config.client)

    app.post('/signup', function (req,res) {
      let user = req.body
      client.saveUser(user, function (err, usr) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)

        res.redirect('/signin')
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto me pasaba porque el npm veia muchos archivos por alguna razón

En primera instancia lo resolviamos de esta forma

```
  echo  fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Aca hay mas detalles https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Comment: Me corrijo compañero, si que funciona, solo lo estaba pasando mal el comando. Gracias @Luciano Montañez